# Consuming an encoded SOAP service on Silverlight / WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, soap

I have a .wsdl file defining a web service, and I want to generate a client object to use the web service. Generating this is unproblematic in a normal .Net project, but it fails when targeting WP7 (the client object gets generated, but does not have all the methods it should have). When doing this directly using SlSvcUtil.exe I get the error message that it does not support operations using SOAP encoding (use='encoded').

The service is run by a third party, and I can't change it.

One solution would be to set up an intermediate server to translate to a format I can read, but I'd like to avoid that. What are my other options? Are there any non-MS libraries that can do this code generation for me? If not, how big of an undertaking would it be to parse the SOAP manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found no solution. It seems there is a lack in the use of SOAP services, when targeting WP7.
In my case I ended up writing my own client class to parse the SOAP manually. The effort was kept within limits but it depends of the complexity of the service.
For more informations about the SOAP protocol I can recommend [w3cschools SOAP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/default.asp). 
It can also be helpful to generate a client object in a normal .Net project and then investigate the network communication with SOAP webservice with fiddler or wireshark.